# Rails export to csv through associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an issue with associations and download via csv export.

My export works if data is present in the sales association, but if there is no data my export remains blank. Removing the `i.sales.each do` part will export `i.item_name` and `i.item_number` fields fine.

So, if there is no data in my association my export remains blank. Is there a method to check if an association has information? I'm looking to include blank fields if no data is present.

I've tried `i.try(:sales).each do |sale|` to no avail.

```
CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
  csv << attributes
  all.each do |i|
    i.sales.each do |sale|
      csv << [
          i.item_name,
          i.item_number,
          sale.try(:sale_cost)
      ]
     end
   end
 end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use left join to get all the records from the first table. This will give you `NULL` values for the associated table, just as you want.

**NOTE:** Please change the references of `Product` model/table with the appropriate one.

**Rails 5 and above**

```
left_joins(:sales).select('products.*, sales.sale_cost').each do |product|
  csv << [
    product.item_name,
    product.item_number,
    (product.sale_cost || 'N/A')
  ]
end
```

**Rails 4 and below**

```
Product.joins("left join sales on products.id = sales.product_id")
       .select('products.*, sales.sale_cost')
       .each do |product|

  csv << [
    product.item_name,
    product.item_number,
    (product.sale_cost || 'N/A')
  ]
end
```

This will result in something like:

```
pencil,12345,20
pencil,12345,10 
eraser,11223,5
box,11333,N/A
```

Comment: This method is spot on. Works a treat. Appreciate your help on this @Deepak.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
  csv << attributes
  all.each do |i|
    if i.sales.present?
     i.sales.each do |sale|
       csv << [
           i.item_name,
           i.item_number,
           sale.try(:sale_cost)
       ]
      end
    else
     csv << [
       i.item_name,
       i.item_number
     ]
    end
   end
 end
```

Comment: Thanks Sascha. I have thought of this, but hoping for a better option. This could be a lot of code if future associations are to be added.

Answer (score 0):

Why not query your sales by association id ?
Assuming your `i` is for an `Item` model name, you can do something like:

```rb
all.each do |i|
  Sale.where(item_id: i.id).each do |sale|
    csv << [
      i.item_name,
      i.item_number,
      sale.try(:sale_cost)
    ]
  end
end
```

or select just the records where sales are present:

```rb
joins(:sales).group('items.id').each do |i|
  i.sales.each do |sale|
    csv << [
      i.item_name,
      i.item_number,
      sale.try(:sale_cost)
    ]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

What @Sascha Mayr says is the normal way to go. Think about the data you want to present in that CSV. How would you call each one of those rows? Now it's a sale, no? But your source model is an item. If a new association were to be added, like "favs", how would you call then each row?

I want to illustrate that the nature of the data to present doesn't correctly fit in a CSV file (2 dimensions) if you start adding info from more associations. Something else should be done then, different CSV files, or grouping by some other concept.